# Linguagem R - Uso de função para evitar repetições de código

Tags: r

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um programa na linguagem R, o mesmo compara dados de dois `data.frame` e grava num terceiro, o programa apresenta varias estruturas condicionais do tipo `else if` dentro de duas estruturas de repetição do tipo `for` sendo que se alguma destas for satisfeita o dado é gravado neste terceiro `data.frame`. A parte do código que faz a gravação dos dados no terceiro `data.frame` se repete varias vezes durante o código gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de criar um tipo de função que eu possa passar os parâmetros para que a mesma faça a gravação sem que precise repeti-la todas as vezes? No exemplo simplificado abaixo coloquei apenas 3 condições, mas no programa real são 13, para este exemplo a parte que se repete sempre é:

```
  tabela3$coluna1[k]<-tabela2$coluna1[j]
  tabela3$coluna2[k]<-tabela2$coluna2[j]
  tabela3$coluna3[k]<-tabela2$coluna3[j]
  tabela3$coluna4[k]<-tabela2$coluna4[j]
  tabela3$coluna5[k]<-tabela2$coluna5[j]
```

obs: tentei criar uma função, mas não funcionaou!

```
k<-1
for(i in 1:nrow(tabela1)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(tabela2)){      
      if (condicao 1 for satisfeia){  

      tabela3$coluna1[k]<-tabela2$coluna1[j]
      tabela3$coluna2[k]<-tabela2$coluna2[j]
      tabela3$coluna3[k]<-tabela2$coluna3[j]
      tabela3$coluna4[k]<-tabela2$coluna4[j]
      tabela3$coluna5[k]<-tabela2$coluna5[j]
       k<- k+1      
    }

      else if(condicao 2 for satisfeita){
      tabela3$coluna1[k]<-tabela2$coluna1[j]
      tabela3$coluna2[k]<-tabela2$coluna2[j]
      tabela3$coluna3[k]<-tabela2$coluna3[j]
      tabela3$coluna4[k]<-tabela2$coluna4[j]
      tabela3$coluna5[k]<-tabela2$coluna5[j]
      k<-k+1 
    }
    else if(condicao 3 for satisfeita){         
      tabela3$coluna1[k]<-tabela2$coluna1[j]
      tabela3$coluna2[k]<-tabela2$coluna2[j]
      tabela3$coluna3[k]<-tabela2$coluna3[j]
      tabela3$coluna4[k]<-tabela2$coluna4[j]
      tabela3$coluna5[k]<-tabela2$coluna5[j]

      k<-k+1       
    }        
}
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei o quão flexível você deseja ao nível dos dois data frames `tabela3` e `tabela2`, mas pelo que entendi você não quer repetir o seguinte código:

```
tabela3$coluna1[k]<-tabela2$coluna1[j]
tabela3$coluna2[k]<-tabela2$coluna2[j]
tabela3$coluna3[k]<-tabela2$coluna3[j]
tabela3$coluna4[k]<-tabela2$coluna4[j]
tabela3$coluna5[k]<-tabela2$coluna5[j]
```

Imagino que a função que você tentou criar (seria melhor se tivesse disponibilizado na pergunta) não funcionou pois funções no R trabalham em diferentes *[ambientes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)*.
Para que as etapas realizadas numa função seja reconhecida fora da função, você precisa atribuir para todos os ambientes (global environment).

Para atribuir um objeto em um ambiente global, você pode simplesmente utilizar `<<-`:

```
fun <- function() {
  tabela3$coluna1[k] <<- tabela2$coluna1[j]
  tabela3$coluna2[k] <<- tabela2$coluna2[j]
  tabela3$coluna3[k] <<- tabela2$coluna3[j]
  tabela3$coluna4[k] <<- tabela2$coluna4[j]
  tabela3$coluna5[k] <<- tabela2$coluna5[j]
}
```

No entanto, o uso do `<<-` não é recomendado, pois aumenta a possibilidade de efeitos colaterias. Mais detalhes sobre isso [aqui](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (página 35).
Uma alternativa é o uso da função `assign()`:

Ao invés de

```
tabela3$coluna1[k] <<- tabela2$coluna1[j]
```

Você usa

```
assign(tabela3$coluna1[k], tabela2$coluna1[j], envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Essas foram as duas maneiras que achei, mas fico curioso se alguém tem algo mais fácil e menos perigoso.

Comment: Testei as duas sugestões, mas a única que funcionou foi  essa "<<-", mas como foi dito pode causar efeitos colaterais! Fico um pouco frustrado com o R pela dificuldade de resolver um problema que é simples de resolver em outras linguagens. Obrigado.

Comment: Qual foi a mensagem de erro para a segunda opção? Se você colocar parte dos seus dados ficaria mais fácil de ajudar: `dput(head(tabela2))` e `dput(head(tabela3))`.

Comment: Esta ai o código só modifiquei o nome das tabelas e colunas, mas a estrutura é a mesma. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
k<-1
for(i in 1:nrow(tabela1)){
  print(k)
  for(j in 1:nrow(tabela2)){


    if(is.na(tabela1$col1[i]) && tabela1$col2[i]=="xx" && isTRUE(tabela2$col3[j]==tabela1$col3[i]) && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && tabela2$col5[j]==1 && isTRUE(tabela1$col6[i]>=tabela2$col6[j])){

      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])
    }

    else if(is.na(tabela1$col1[i]) && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && tabela2$col5[j]==0 && isTRUE(tabela1$col6[i]>=tabela2$col6[j])){

      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 

    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="2") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="2") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(1-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="2.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="2.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(1-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="3") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="3") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(1-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="3.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="3.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(1-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="4") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="4") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(6-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="4.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="4.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(6-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="5") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="5") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(6-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="5.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="5.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(6-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="6") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="6") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="6.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="6.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="7") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="7") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="7.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="7.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="8") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="8") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="8.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="8.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 

    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="9") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="9") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }


    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="9.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="9.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="10") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="10") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(20-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="11") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="11") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(40-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }

    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="11.1") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="11.1") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(40-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }



    else if(isTRUE(tabela1$col1[i]=="12") && isTRUE(tabela2$col1[j]=="12") && tabela2$col4[j]==1 && isTRUE(40-tabela1$col8[i]>0)){


      tabela1$col6[i]<-tabela1$col6[i]-1
      tabela1$col1[i]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela2$col4[j]<-0

      tabela3$col12Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col11[i])
      tabela3$col10Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col10[j])
      tabela3$col8Def[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col8[i])
      tabela3$col1Def[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col1[j])
      tabela3$col3[k]<-as.character(tabela2$col3[j])
      tabela3$col9[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col9[i])
      tabela3$col2[k]<-as.character(tabela1$col2[i])

      k<-k+1 


    }



    tabela1$col8<- tabela1$col6-tabela1$col6
  }

}
```